# How to hide album art, and display a visualizer in an android music player , similar to google music android app?

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, visualizer, android-music-player

i am making an music player in android, i have a list with album art and all the song information in it. now when i play a certain song i want the album art to change and instead i want a 3 bar visualizer there similar to google music player, equalizer+ music player. I dont seem to understand how to do a 3 bar visualizer, and i am not sure wether those 3 bars are visualizers. any suggestion how to go about it would help, i am attaching two pics of google music before the song is played and during the song is playing, notice the 3 bars in the left.[image before playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyQo2.png)

[Image after playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5IfZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Android Visualizer](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer) library available that has a visualization mode with frequency distributions (the 'bar visualization'):
[image][gif](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/raw/master/demo/demo-1.gif)

There are various other visualization modes available, the source code of the Bar visualizer is available [here](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/renderer/BarGraphRenderer.java) and can be customized to fit your needs.

A demo of how to use the library with the MediaPlayer is included in the project.
https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer